# Use a subtype with mypy

Tags: python, mypy

I have a function that takes a list of objects and prints it.

```
bc_directives = t.Union[
    data.Open,
    data.Close,
    data.Commodity,
    data.Balance,
    data.Pad,
    data.Transaction,
    data.Note,
    data.Event,
    data.Query,
    data.Price,
    data.Document,
    data.Custom,
]


def print_entries(entries: t.List[bc_directives], file: t.IO) -> None:
    pass
```

but if I do :

```
accounts: t.List[bc_directives] = []

for entry in data.sorted(entries):
  if isinstance(entry, data.Open):
    accounts.append(entry)
    continue
accounts = sorted(accounts, key=lambda acc: acc.account)

# the attribute account does not exist for the other class.

print_entries(accounts)
```

Here I have a problem.
mypy complain that the other class does not have account attribute. Of course it is designed like that.

> Item "Commodity" of "Union[Open, Close, Commodity, Balance, Pad, Transaction, Note, Event, Query, Price, Document, Custom]" has no attribute "account"

If I change the definition of accounts to `t.List[data.Open]`, mypy complains when I used `print_entries`. (but it should be the best).
So how can I use use a subset of a union and get mypy to not complain?

Answer (score 1):

You should make `print_entries` accept a *Sequence*, not a *List*. Here is a simplified example demonstrating a type-safe version of your code:

```
from typing import IO, List, Sequence, Union

class Open:
    def __init__(self, account: int) -> None:
        self.account = account

class Commodity: pass


Directives = Union[Open, Commodity]

def print_entries(entries: Sequence[Directives]) -> None:
    for entry in entries:
        print(entry)


accounts: List[Open] = [Open(1), Open(2), Open(3)]
print_entries(accounts)
```

The reason why making `print_entries` accept a *list* of your directive types is because it would introduce a potential bug in your code -- if `print_entries` were to do `entries.append(Commodities())`, your list of accounts would no longer contain only Open objects, breaking type safety.

Sequence is a read-only version of a list and so sidesteps this problem entirely, letting it have fewer restrictions. (That is, List[T] is a subclass of Sequence[T]).

---

More precisely, we say that Sequence is a *covariant* type: if if we have some child type C that subclasses a parent type P (if P :> C), it is always true that Sequence[P] :> Sequence[C].

In contrast, Lists are *invariant*: List[P] and List[C] will have no inherent relationship to each other, and neither subclasses the other.

Here is a tabular summary of the different kinds of relationships generic types can be designed to have:

```
              | Foo[P] :> Foo[C] | Foo[C] :> Foo[P] | Used for
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Covariant     | True             | False            | Read-only types
Contravariant | False            | True             | Write-only types
Invariant     | False            | False            | Both readable and writable types
Bivariant     | True             | True             | Nothing (not type safe)
```