# Python Typing: How to handle List type hinting with different element type in subclasses?

Tags: python, subclass, type-hinting, mypy, pyright

I am trying to understand how type hinting works in Python - especially in children classes. I had this issue while working on a project and was able to recreate the issue in an example, presented below.

Environment:

- Python: 3.9.7
- mypy: 0.910
- OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Example Code:

```py
from typing import List
import math

class Shape:
    def area(self):
        ...
    def perimeter(self):
        ...

class Circle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, r):
        self.r = r

    def area(self):
        return math.pi * self.r * self.r

    def perimeter(self):
        return 2 * math.pi * self.r

class Cube(Shape):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        self.corners = 4

    def area(self):
        return self.x * self.x

    def perimeter(self):
        return self.x * 4

class A:
    
    def __init__(self, element: Shape):
        self.element = element

class B(A):

    def __init__(self, element: Cube):
        super().__init__(element)
```

What I don't understand is how to fix this issue:

```py
class AList:
    
    def __init__(self, elements: List[Shape]):
        self.elements = elements

class BList(AList):

    def __init__(self, elements: List[Cube]):
        super().__init__(elements) # This line is causing the Pyright error

        print([x.corners for x in elements])
```

I get the following Pyright error in `BList` class' `super().__init__(elements)`:

```
[Pyright reportGeneralTypeIssues] [E] Argument of type "List[Cube]" cannot be assigned to parameter "elements" of type "List[Shape]" in function "__init__" TypeVar "_T@list" is invariant "Cube" is incompatible with "Shape"
```

I also get the following error message in mypy:

```
(pymmdt) eduardo@avocado-MS-7C83:~/Downloads$ mypy example.py
example.py:49: error: Argument 1 to "__init__" of "AList" has incompatible type "List[Cube]"; expected "List[Shape]"
example.py:49: note: "List" is invariant -- see https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#variance
example.py:49: note: Consider using "Sequence" instead, which is covariant
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Will continue working on, but any suggestions/feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Comment: `List`, since it is mutable, is invariant to be type safe. As the error message states, you can "Consider using "Sequence" instead, which is covariant"

Comment: See [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#covariance-and-contravariance) and especially [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0483/#covariance-and-contravariance), and perhaps [here](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#variance-of-generic-types),

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you so much for the help and resources. Very helpful :). If you would like, you can write an solution and I would more than happy mark it as the answer to my question.

Comment: Side note: remove the `2 * ` from calculating `Circle`'s `area`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mypy trouble with inheritance of objects in lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305636/mypy-trouble-with-inheritance-of-objects-in-lists)

Comment: also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60254416/5986907) and likely others